# PSCP copy files windows to windows over lan fails

Tags: windows, putty, pscp

Trying to copy from PC A to PC B but getting network error

- Username and password are correct
- Firewall is off
- Able to ping each other
- Folder `C:\PCB` to `C:\B`

I tried:

```
PSCP.exe -pw 1qaz@WSX admin@10.0.0.2:/PCB/*.* C:\B
```

> Fatal: Network error: Connection refused

Comment: What SSH server have you installed on 10.0.0.2?

Comment: can it work without SSH installed on both computers?

Comment: [SCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_copy) is based on SSH. In your case you need an SSH server on the remote (`10.0.0.2`) machine; SSH server (if any) on the local computer is irrelevant because your target "address" (`C:\B`) is just a local path. So what SSH server have you installed on `10.0.0.2`?

Answer (score 4):

Since PuTTY's `pscp` is an SFTP (SSH file transfer) client, it needs an SSH & SFTP service to be installed on the remote computer. Windows does not have one by default, and so you get "Connection refused" because **nothing is listening on the SSH port.**

To make `pscp` work you'll need to install, for example, OpenSSH that comes with Windows 10, or Bitvise WinSSHd, or OpenSSH via Cygwin.

Your alternative option is to use regular Windows' "file sharing" (SMB). Share a folder on PC A and copy the files directly using `copy`/`xcopy`/`robocopy`.